# + operator in Kotlin gives "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:"

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin by doing exercises on exercism.com. I am currently working on [triangles](https://exercism.org/tracks/kotlin/exercises/triangle). The code has the following test that I'm trying to make pass:

```
class TriangleTest {
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun `triangle inequality violation - last is greater then sum of others `() {
        Triangle(1, 1, 3)
    }
}
```

My solution:

```
class Triangle<out T : Number>(private val a: T, private val b: T, private val c: T) {
    init {
        // ...

        if (a + b <= c) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ highlights the `+` red and gives the following error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.plus(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.plus(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
...
```

This goes on for like 100 lines with other `plus()` methods from array and collection types.

Why can't I add two numbers in the `init` block here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Kotlin does not provide a `plus` overload for adding two `Number`s. One way is to convert the `Number`s to `Double`s add then perform operations on them. Also, Kotlin provides a handy [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) function for such validations.

```kotlin
class Triangle(val a: Number, val b: Number, val c: Number) {

    init {
        val (x, y, z) = listOf(a.toDouble(), b.toDouble(), c.toDouble())
        require(x + y > z)
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. And thanks for the `require()` tip.

Comment: p..s. `require()` requires the logic is flipped: `require(x + y > z)`.

Comment: So with the template version I originally posted, Kotlin doesn't use the value passed to `T` to determine which `plus()` to call?

Comment: Yeah, at compile time, Kotlin only knows that `T` is a `Number` and there isn't any `plus` overload for adding two `Number`s. (And thanks for pointing out that flipped sign, edited the answer)

Comment: In Kotlin (and Java), `Number` is far less useful than you might think, I'm afraid. It lets you convert any instance into any of the primitive types, but that's all. It doesn't let you do arithmetic, or any other processing. (It doesn't even let you convert numbers into non-primitive subclasses such as `BigDecimal`…) And since _all_ the possible conversions can be lossy, you can't even accept a `Number` and then do all your processing in `Long`s (which can't store non-integer values) or `Double`s (which doesn't have as big a range as `Long`…